# How can I scale an image in a way that it is bit-wise identical?

Tags: ruby

I have the following piece of code

```
image = Magick::Image.read(original_image_path).first
image.change_geometry!(@attributes['width']+"x"+
    @attributes['height']) { |cols, rows, img|
    newimg = img.resize(cols, rows)
    newimg.write(new_filename)
}
```

which scales an image for my blog. This happens every time when I build the blog (it is a static site generator). The problem is that all files which have changed get automatically committed. So I want that when I run this scaling piece of code two times that it gives the same results.

Currently, imagemagick seems to add exif data (e.g. a timestamp?).

Comment: Aren't your compiled assets ignored by git?

Comment: @SparK I use [GitHub pages](https://pages.github.com/). If I would ignore those, I would not have any images on my blog.

Comment: It seems like the right solution would be to not run this code when the original image hasn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't speak Ruby, but at the command-line, you can suppress generation of dates in a JPEG (in fact, probably any) file like this:

```
convert input.jpg -strip +set date:create +set date:modify result.jpg
```

You can test that by stripping a file, running an MD5 checksum and waiting a few seconds and repeating the process and see that the checksum stays the same.

In the specific case of PMG files, you can use the library's ability to exclude specific chunks like this:

```
convert input.png -define png:exclude-chunks=date result.png
```